# How to provide git revision/version for useful bug report?

Tags: git, bug-reporting

I compile and test git versions of open source software. When I find bugs, I want to write concise, useful reports.

How do I provide useful git commit or "version" information in a bug report, so that developers immediately know what "revision" I have tested?

I know of

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

which creates output like

```
a2e2e93c85b2c7431c365fd52b4456d28db9d531
```

which might not be too useful because it's not easily readable to humans.

Answer (score 0):

```
git describe --tags --always
```

will produce something nice and readable like:

```
v15.11.80-38-ga2e2e93
```

*Thanks to qsuscs on irc.freenode#git for this helpful info. A similar suggestion can be found in a [Hacker News thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9815583).*